# sqlite fts4 can not use offsets funtion when use group by

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I have two table:
table 1:
fts virtual table

docid Long auto increase,
content Text, (fts column)

table 2:
meta data table

docid Long(foreigner key of table1 docid),
username Text,
timestamp Long

sql:
select table1.docid content, username, MAX(timestamp) as time, offsets(table1) from table1, table2 where content Match "a" AND table1.docid = table2.docid group by username order by timestamp desc limit 3;

this sql will not execute, but i delete "group by username", it can execute. why?

Comment: Works for me, unless I remove the GROUP BY.

Comment: does you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `offsets` function works only on FTS tables, but the result of a join is no longer an FTS table (depending on how the query optimizer decides to execute the join).

You have to do the search in two steps instead:

```
SELECT docid,
       content,
       offsets,
       username,
       MAX(timestamp)
FROM (SELECT docid,
             content,
             offsets(table1) AS offsets
      FROM table1
      WHERE content MATCH 'a')
JOIN table2 USING (docid)
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: it still occur unable to use function offsets in the requested context error, my sql is
SELECT type, MIN(subtype) as minSubtype, entity_id, aux_index, timestamp, content, offset FROM (SELECT docid, content, offsets(FtsIndexContact) as offset FROM FtsIndexContact WHERE content MATCH ?) JOIN FtsMetaContact USING(docid) WHERE type = 131075 AND status >= 0 GROUP BY aux_index ORDER BY talktime desc LIMIT 4;